Questions of Identity
After seeing society and how words change and standards change. I notice how identities and ways of identities change as well. I noticed that most non muslims seem not wrong when they see it as a social construct or up to the culture. When I look at islams position on this wishy washyness of identity I see no islamic text on it other than urf. I am very confused as this same thing is used to act like gender is some made up thing. What's Islam's answer to identity and what exactly is the identity of one's culture, gender, status.. as ones culture can change and status or role but gender.. I am very confused. (PLEASE ISLAMIC REFERENCES, I don't want a "in my opinion" answer and sorry long question, jazakallah)

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. Well we neither want opinion-based answers, we look for answers reflecting the well-evidenced view of scholars.

What do you mean by Islam's view on identity? You mean how to distinguish between what Islam is and what Muslims' culture is?

May Allah reward everyone who responded. I just want to know what is the Islamic view on identity as a concept. Is identity yours or some and what parts of it is. We follow prophet muhammad sallalahu alayhi wasalam but we also have distinct character and roles. I wanted clarity on the objectives on our roles and identity as it is seen as made up to the disbelievers or open to the people like how language evolves but language is originally from Allah but we are allowed to add upon it like innovate but prophet forbid bid'ah in religion so I wanted to know what parts of identity that can change
